# finding ratio of areas of triangle using other ratio

Tags: geometry

[image]

$OA/AP = 1/2$

$OB/OQ= 1/4$

$MN/NP= 1/4$

m is the midpoint of OQ

Calculate the value of area of triangle OPQ / area of Triangle PNQ

My workings till I got confused with myself -

Area of OPQ / Area of PMQ = 4/2 = 2

Area of PQM / area of PNQ = 5/4

And then someone told me that -

Area of OPQ / Area of PNQ

= Area of OPQ / Area of PMQ X Area of PMQ / Area of PNQ

I'm not sure about what's the use of multiplying these 2 ratios together .. Can I get help. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Let $[ABC]$ be the area of $\triangle{ABC}$.

Then, note that
$$\frac{[OPQ]}{[PNQ]}=\frac{[OPQ]}{[PNQ]}\times 1=\frac{[OPQ]}{[PNQ]}\times \frac{[PMQ]}{[PMQ]}=\frac{[OPQ]}{[PMQ]}\times\frac{[PMQ]}{[PNQ]}=2\times\frac 54$$